# Mouse listener keeps value after close and reopen procedure recreate mouse listener

Tags: java, mouselistener

In my Java application I use a mouse listener to determine which record is selected into table (from MySQL).

When the user presses the mouse into the table to selecting some record, and then close procedure, reopen it, the mouse listener keeps the value and it seems like the user again selected the same record onto table, but would be a empty.

And, after that, this value is kept (not cleaned) after clicking onto another record into table. How could I empty that after closing procedure and reopen it?

I tried `table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()` that closes procedure, but it's still not working.
This is a mouse listener:

```
jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jTable1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
});

 private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    jTable1.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    try {
        int row=jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(jTable1.getSelectedRow());  
        if (row !=-1) {
        //some code
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Greska:" + e);
    }
```

When closing procedure:

```
public void zatvoriProzor() {
    jTable1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    pMeniIfa.PocMeniZatvoriVel2();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question, hopefully making it more clear. But it is hard for us to help if we cannot see your code. Could you add a [mcve] of the problem? You can [edit] it into your question. If we can see some code, then maybe we can help you. Good luck!